# Search td.class in table js

Tags: javascript

I'm going through the lines and looking for class "bi"

```
let table = document.querySelector('#table');
let rows = table.rows;

for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   if (document.querySelector('.bi') !== null) {
     let redBlock = document.querySelector('.bi')
     console.log("redBlock" + redBlock.innerHTML)
    }
```

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>5.13</td>
<td>4.20</td>
<td class="bi">6.16</td> \\ console.log redBlock - 6.16
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>1.13</td>
<td>4.10</td>
<td class="bi">7.20</td>\\ console.log redBlock - 6.16
  </tr>
</table>
```

without result :

```
  let redBlock = rows[i].querySelector('.bi') \\ console.log redBlock null
```

how to get the values in each row?

Comment: You are not referencing the row.... You are selecting them for the whole document.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using querySelectorAll?

Comment: `rows[i].querySelector('.bi')` should work fine. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. See [How to create Stack Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212). You do not have an element with ID `table`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looking at the document every single time. So because of that you are selecting the same element every time. You need to reference the row and use querySelector from that point.

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#table tbody tr");
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  const cell = rows[i].querySelector("td.bi");
  if (cell) console.log(cell.innerText);
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>5.13</td>
    <td>4.20</td>
    <td class="bi">6.16</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.13</td>
    <td>4.10</td>
    <td class="bi">7.20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

now you could just loop over all the cells with the class and avoid the row loop

```js
const biCells = document.querySelectorAll("#table td.bi");
biCells.forEach(cell => {
  console.log(cell.innerText);
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>5.13</td>
    <td>4.20</td>
    <td class="bi">6.16</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.13</td>
    <td>4.10</td>
    <td class="bi">7.20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i reference the row 
let table = document.querySelector('#table');
let rows = table.rows;

Comment: @ВиталийЮрьевич not with how you look for the cell in the row. You look at the entire document, not the table row.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ppjln/pen/oEZXjV?editors=1111